# How can I create a link for Windows with install4j

Tags: install4j

How can I create a link for Windows with install4j? I don't mean a desktop link, because for that there's a specific action "Add a desktop link".
I mean a link (to a launcher e.g.) in anywhere on my system (in my home folder e.g.)

The action "Create a symbolic link" doesn't work on Windows - is that correct?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "Create start menu entry" action with an absolute path in the "Entry name" property. Only if the entry name is relative will the link be created in the start menu.